# SELECT in COALESCE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do the following in MySQL:

```
UPDATE
    x
SET
    y = COALESCE(SELECT z FROM table WHERE a = b AND c = d AND e = f LIMIT 1,
                 SELECT z FROM table WHERE a = b AND c = d LIMIT 1,
                 SELECT z FROM table WHERE a = b LIMIT 1);
```

It sounds very valid to me. I'm trying to update a column with **the best suitable value**. If I can find a record matching the 3 criteria -> that's the one I need. Else the one suiting 2 criteria, else a record matching just one criterion.

I can do this in 3 update queries, but I don't understand why this isn't working. According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

`COALESCE returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.`

That's **exactly** what I need. but it gives the following error:

`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT'`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Are you able to provide a full query, i.e. without your  generalisation in there.  It would help to provide more accurate advice.

Comment: It's just a 1064 syntax error. My query is basically this. It gives a syntax error exactly at the SELECT within the COALESCE.

Comment: Have you tried putting each of those subselects into their own pair of parentheses (as is usually necessary for subselects)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is presumably that you are getting more than 1 z value returned by the subselects.  You can only get one.

You could try:

```
update x
set y = (select z from t where a = b
         order by (case when a = b and c = d and e = f then 1
                        when a = b and c = d then 2
                        else 3
                   end)
         limit 1
        );
```

However, your specific syntax error is that you need parentheses around the selects.  So this is the syntactically correct version:

```
UPDATE
    x
SET
    y = COALESCE((SELECT z FROM table WHERE a = b AND c = d AND e = f LIMIT 1),
                 (SELECT z FROM table WHERE a = b AND c = d LIMIT 1),
                 (SELECT z FROM table WHERE a = b LIMIT 1));
```

Comment: I edited my post to include the LIMIT 1 suggestion. The error persists, but your way seams very clean and is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing though; why doesn't COALESCE work? Isn't my example exactly what COALESCE is for?

Comment: You can also actually remove the a=b from the case, as the WHERE statement assumes that already.

COALESCE is for when you have values rather than handling subqueries

Comment: @Simonatmso.net . . . That is totally true.  I was trying to make the code as transparent as possible to show what it is doing.

Comment: For completeness sake, you might wanna add 'END' to your CASE. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to advise without more details but something like this may work

```
UPDATE
    x
SET y = COALESCE(
    ( SELECT z FROM table WHERE a = b AND c = d AND e = f LIMIT 1),
    ( SELECT z FROM table WHERE a = b AND c = d LIMIT 1 ),
    ( SELECT z FROM table WHERE a = b LIMIT 1 )
);
```

Ensures that each subquery only returns up to 1 row.